# Sequelize can not connect to postgressql in Deno

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, deno

I wanted to connect Postgres database via deno and using [sequelize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize) package. Here's my code in deno:

`db.ts`

```js
import { Sequelize } from "npm:sequelize@6.32.1";
// deno-types="npm:@types/pg@8.10.2"
import pg from "npm:pg@8.11.1";
import hstore from "npm:pg-hstore@2.3.4";

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    "postgres://default:****@example.com:5432/test",
    {
        dialectOptions: {
            ssl: { require: true, rejectUnauthorized: false },
        },
    }
);



sequelize
    .authenticate()
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Connection has been established successfully.");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error("Unable to connect to the database", err);
    });
```

the error that it gives me:

<sub>Unable to connect to the database SequelizeConnectionError: tlssock._start is not a function
at Client._connectionCallback (file:///**/Caches/deno/npm/registry.npmjs.org/sequelize/6.32.1/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:147:20)</sub>

`Error Log:`

[image: full error log]

I tried the same exact configuration using Node, and installed all dependencies. (pg, pg-hstore and sequelize using NPM)

and It's working.

`console.log`

<sub>Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result
you are connected</sub>

Is there a way to implement this in Deno? Am I missing something?

Comment: This seems like an issue with Deno, and I let them know it. You can track it at https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/19983.

Comment: The issue was resolved, and it will be shipped in Deno’s next release. You can then try again.